# H264 usb capture in android

Tags: android, camera, usb

I have been trying to capture the video through usb on an android mobile phone using
https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simpledoublewebcams2/src/3ba4b383f53338e161d36ceb007f5789662be35c/jni/ImageProc/ImageProc.c?at=master

The only problem here is that they are using MJPEG format but I want it to capture in h264. When I am changing it
fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;'
to
fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_H264;

I am getting the following wrror while running.

VIDIOC_S_FMT error 22, Invalid argument

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong ??

Comment: No seems like the driver or support is missing in android and linux currently.